# Netbeans maven dependency

Tags: maven, netbeans

I'm trying to build a project in Netbeans so i import the project and run it, while building i got this,

> Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ear-plugin:2.6 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ear-plugin:jar:2.6: Could not
>   transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ear-plugin:pom:2.6
>   from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to
>   repo.maven.apache.org:80 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.60.215]
>   failed: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]
>
> To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e
>   switch. Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

This happened while downloading Downloading: 
`http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/2.6/maven-ear-plugin-2.6.pom`

I checked the proxy and test the connection, everything's okay !

Any ideas ?

I'm using netbeans 8.1 on windows

Comment: Have you checked your Netbeans proxy settings (Options->General) and your firewall?

Comment: Yes, the connection works fine, i run `Test connection`